# webdriver returns error of communication with browser on parallel test run with selenium grid on local machine

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-grid, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running tests on local machine on Mac OS
Python 2.7.5

Selenium hub:

> java -jar ~/Downloads/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -role hub

Selenium node:

```
java -jar ~/Downloads/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver -role node http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register
```

chromedriver is:

> ChromeDriver 2.10.267517

I'm using behave framework and open new instance of chrome driver before each scenarion and use quit method avery after scenario hook.

When i'm running tests one by one a have no problems.

When i running tests in parallel on firefox driver everything is fine but with crome i have unexpected behavior.

When first step in number of parallel tests on one node is over all other steps crashed with:

> WebDriverException: Message: u"Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.\nBuild info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d', time: '2014-06-03 17:42:03'\nSystem info: host: 'point', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.2', java.version: '1.7.0_51'\nDriver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver" ; Stacktrace:

On selenium grid console i see that first selenium session is closed but all others are present.

I'm sure that i have only one instance of driver per test.
i run tests parallel with multiprocessing module support:

```
for n in range(N):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_wrapper, args=(compiled_cmd,))
    jobs.append(p)
    p.start()
    time.sleep(3)

for j in jobs:
    j.join()
    if j.exitcode != 0:
        sys.exit(1)
```

I appreciate any advice on my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as if your driver is being stored a static or some such global variable.

Posting your initialization code may show the issue

Comment: I'm storing driver at "context" variable of behave framework. But context variable is not the same due to every subprocess has its own launch of behave framework

Comment: also I ran tests in parallel with isolated envs, but problem still exists.

Comment: Ok, my knowledge of Python is limited, but the behaviour you are seeing is often caused by parallel tests each creating their own driver but overwriting each others instance. Hopefully you will find an answer soon.

Comment: The answer was use linux platform (e.g. Ubuntu) not MacOS! :)

Answer (score 0):

Question was resolved by moving on linux platform (Ubuntu).